# Convert Python floating-point into C# decimal

Tags: python, c#, decimal, python.net

I'm trying to convert a floating-point number in Python into [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0) in C# using pythonnet.

Let's say there is one number `0.0234337688540165776476565071`.

I have tried this in two ways:

1. using `float()`

   ```py
   from System import Decimal
   Decimal(0.0234337688540165776476565071)
   # Same with Decimal(float(0.0234337688540165776476565071))

   0.02343377
   ```
2. using native Python `Decimal`

   ```py
   from System import Decimal
   from decimal import Decimal as PyDecimal
   Decimal(PyDecimal("0.0234337688540165776476565071"))

   # This loses every number under the floating-point
   0
   ```

What should I do?

Comment: The value returned from PyDecimal("0.0234337688540165776476565071") is a decimal do why are you putting Decimal() arond the results?  If you want more accuracy use Double.  A Double is 64 bits while a Float is 32 bits.  Decimal gives better accuracy than float with 32 bits for most numbers because it is using a logrithmic algorithm.  Double and Float uses exponential algorithm

Comment: `PyDecimal` above is native Python type, and I'm trying to convert Python's `Decimal` into `System.Decimal` of C#. That's why I did `Decimal(PyDecimal(0.212....))`.

Comment: Why would Python Decimal be any dffient from Ne3 Decimal?   They both are IEEE 754.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the examples in your question, it looks like you are trying to convert a string to `System.Decimal`. For that, `System.Decimal` has a [`Parse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_):

```
from System import Decimal

Decimal.Parse("0.0234337688540165776476565071")
```

Note: you probably also need to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` depending on your scenario.

Comment: This is really simple and works for me!! Thank you! Why I didn't know this...`Parse()`

Answer (score 0):

If you cast a string to a python float then it will be truncated to 64-bit and you will lose precision. You will have to use a [different constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Boolean_System_Byte_) for `System.Decimal`. For instance:

```
public Decimal (int lo, int mid, int hi, bool isNegative, byte scale);
```

Skipping validation, it might look something like

```
from System import Decimal
from System import Int32, Boolean, Byte

def str_to_csp_decimal(number: str) -> Decimal:
    """ convert a string to a C# Decimal """
    is_negative = number[0] == "-"
    abs_value = number[1:] if is_negative else number

    has_fraction = "." in abs_value 
    if has_fraction:
        integer, fraction = abs_value.split(".")
        scale = len(fraction)                # denominator = 10 ** scale
        numerator = int(integer + fraction)  # no precision loss for integers
    else:
        scale = 0                            # denominator == 1
        numerator = int(abs_value)
    
    assert numerator < (2 << 96), "Decimal only has 96 bits of precision"

    # split the numerator into the lower, mid, and high 32 bits
    mask = 0xFFFFFFFF
    low = Int32(numerator & mask)
    mid = Int32((numerator >> 32) & mask)
    high = Int32((numerator >> 64) & mask)

    return Decimal(low, mid, high, Boolean(is_negative), Byte(scale))

str_to_csp_decimal("0.0234337688540165776476565071").ToString()
```

Comment: Why not just use `Decimal.Parse` method?

Comment: Your answer is also amazing. Thank you so much for this.